# What is the source that you can not have benefit from miracles?

Tags: sources-mekorot, talmud-gemara, miracle

There is a famous concept that a person is not allowed to have benefit from a miracle. What is its talmudic source and what does it apply to?

Comment: BAbylonian Talmud, Taanis 24

Comment: @RebChaimHaQoton, flesh that out (add, in particular, an answer to "and what does it apply to?"), and it sounds like you've got a good answer to post below.

Comment: what about the splitting of the sea, the manna, etc.?

Comment: Didn't Eliyahu benefit from being fed by ravens?